Why is the voltage in a Solar Cell not equal to the band gap?
I have been researching about Solar Cells, and think I understand the basics on how a Photon hits the depletion region creating a free electron and a hole, with the hole going to the P-Type side and the electron going to the N-Type side.
My question is related to the potential difference between these two sides. Surely, if the electron needs 1.1v of energy to be bumped up into the conduction band, it has 1.1v of potential energy. Especially, since it is going back round to go back down to drop into the valence band again (-1.1v of energy).
However, what I have found is that the typical average of a silicon single-junction solar cell is only 0.5-0.7 cell. I understand there can be re-combination losses, but I don't understand how these effect the other free electrons with the energy of being in the conduction band.
What is the cause of the solar-cells potential difference being limited and not the same as the band-gap. Would there be any way of making the solar cell voltage equal to the band gap.
